# Why am I getting a "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" for this using the len function on a set?

Tags: python, set

I'm getting an error for a piece of python code I wrote that shouldn't

This is the function I wrote and the input I gave it.

```
#turn list of ints into set, remove val from set, and return the length of the set without val.
def foo(nums,val):
    sett = set(nums)
    sett_without_val = sett.remove(val)
    return len(sett_without_val)


print(foo([3,2,2,3],3))
```

sett should be {3,2}
sett_without_val should be {2}
and len(sett_without_val) should be 1. I'm not supposed to get this error:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I thought it had something to do with the remove method I used, so I used discard instead and still got the exact same error message.

Comment: Because `set.remove` is a function that updates the set in-place. It returns nothing i.e. `None`, which is what the error is complaining about (You cannot call `len` on a `None` object)

Comment: If you want to geek   around, you can look at the source code. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c  Line 1876-1900 set.remove returns none

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` method of `set` is changing it in-place, so

```
sett_without_val = sett.remove(val)
```

returns `None` and assign it to the variable,
working code is

```
def foo(nums,val):
    sett = set(nums)
    sett.remove(val)
    return len(sett)


print(foo([3,2,2,3],3))
```

output:

```
1
```

Explanation:

```
1. [3, 2, 2, 3] 
2. after set(): {3, 2} 
3. after .remove(3): {2} 
4. after len(): 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sett.remove(val) does not return anything.

Try this

```
def foo(nums,val):
      sett = set(nums)
      sett.remove(val)
      return len(sett)
```